# how to customize the image after capturing the image from the uiimagepicker

Tags: ios, xcode5, uiimagepickercontroller

I need to customize the square frame that comes after when we select a image from the camera using uiimagepickerController
 [image]

Comment: how did you create that square view in camera?

Comment: if controller's  allosEditing = YES;

Answer (score 1):

UIImagePickerController comes with a handy method to enable editing.

```
UIImagePickerController *mediaUI = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
[mediaUI setAllowsEditing:YES];
```

calling this method should help.